# How can i insert Multiple html into the modal through Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Actually My question is after onclick My Modal is appear and i can insert multiple things into the Modal and i can do this through

```
(.html("abc");)
```

But the above syntax is insert only one string if i append multiple String it's shows error
Here is my Code:

```
    echo "<script>
   function myFunction(order){
   $('.modal-body').html(order.order_id);
   $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: false}); /#myModal is the body of the Modal 
       }
   </script>";
```

Comment: JQuery inside a PHP echo like that will cause problems: PHP will attempt to interpret `$('.modal-body')` as a PHP variable because of the `$` sign. Either use HEREDOC syntax, a single quoted string or escape the dollar sign `\$` : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php.

Comment: .html() replaces the element's old html with the new one, Try to use .append instead. also you don't need to execute $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: false}); each timeyou should call this onc.

Comment: @Khaled .append create new error if i create a Secound Moda it append with the last value also(means first value is also shown in the modal)

Comment: @CD001 is it right in the php code
 **echo "Order Number : " . "<script> ('.modal-body').html(order.order_id) </script>" ."<br>";**

Comment: Surprisingly PHP doesn't choke on it - probably because `$(` is not a valid start to a PHP variable. However, your comment in the JS is broken `/#myModal` needs another leading `/`

Comment: @CD001 Actually i did all the way but problem still same

Answer (score 0):

Now i find out the soloution we can use this:

```
     $('.modal-body').html('<b>Order Number</b>: '+order.order_id +
 '<br>'+'<b>Order Date:</b>' + ' ' +order.created_date+ '<br>'+'<b>Table Number:</b>' + ' ' +order.uid + '<br>'+'<b>Status:</b> ' + ' ' +order.status+ '<br>'+'<b>Title:</b>' + ' ' +order.title + '<br>'+'<b>Quantity:</b>' + ' ' +order.quantity+ '<br>'+'<b>Personalization:</b>' + ' ' +order.personalization);
```